# SSH CA-signed key does not work from certain hosts

Tags: ssh, debian, ssh-keys, certificate-authority

I've tried to setup CA signed ssh user keys.

I got my configuration working on most clients, there seems to be problem on a few specific ones.
The key verification fails and they are prompted for password.

When I try to connect to the sftp user (one of the principals in the ssh key) this is what appears in the server ssh log

```
Failed publickey for sftp from 192.168.99.13 port 55830 ssh2: RSA-CERT SHA256:yYgNW3M5txAtXjj6jXnBVf6vI4NUnoNvfWPPtS4pewU ID debby (serial 0) CA RSA SHA256:W78bubCEvj75KxHJcasa9aclOddsDfKiOLd2uozMqKI
```

Both the user key and the CA signing key hash seem to be correct.
This works from several other client no problem including:

- Arch linux OpenSSH_9.3p2, OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023
- Fedora linux OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023

The problematic clients are:

- Debian OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
- Ubuntu OpenSSH_9.0p1 Ubuntu-1ubuntu7.3, OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022

With the Debian client I even tried to copy its `~/.ssh` folder locally to verify it is signed correctly.

The connection works.
This is the only difference in the server ssh log:

```
debug1: cert: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
Accepted certificate ID "debby" (serial 0) signed by RSA CA SHA256:W78bubCEvj75KxHJcasa9aclOddsDfKiOLd2uozMqKI via /etc/ssh/ca_user_key.pub
```

I've made sure the permissions and ownership of the `~/.ssh` directories are the same.

Has anyone ever encountered anything similar or have any more troubleshooting tips?

EDIT: Here is the relevant part of the DEBUG3 log

```
debug1: trying public key file /home/sftp/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 5 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug2: /home/sftp/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: check options: '@cert-authority *.dev.tbscz ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQDagkuT1W+CXkdkhkgCEWHTekY/QF9To4Ls0UMukW0VURcnER465QoUbOFzsZ6wZ1TkxNv32M9kgrUaCOZayyylYr1asLKgGx8KQayCoTgay06b5NLG6kFw7+zE/uk7lS5AXPS2tdzO9qxb7agtGcr9nyrUqyqA0ux+Kox03RlciazXS2b0BLzDYfIAvKcCk2peaQsogh0JIZxXNF8eVJZ9LGKh6XbQqxw1uwjizlMCXwzVwL1Qo/sTsDbo67lrIdH5mjX2HapCFbMz31BTX0IjJ+qqpBwDS2ydH4zpyOmHmIqn3kOh1DgCfZFtXSYzCKERKx5R5n5KtJShvjh7w7LBuD7VDB8u85Us7OpUUM7Ie+JbAPlxfGJ0I
debug2: /home/sftp/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: advance: '*.dev.tbscz ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQDagkuT1W+CXkdkhkgCEWHTekY/QF9To4Ls0UMukW0VURcnER465QoUbOFzsZ6wZ1TkxNv32M9kgrUaCOZayyylYr1asLKgGx8KQayCoTgay06b5NLG6kFw7+zE/uk7lS5AXPS2tdzO9qxb7agtGcr9nyrUqyqA0ux+Kox03RlciazXS2b0BLzDYfIAvKcCk2peaQsogh0JIZxXNF8eVJZ9LGKh6XbQqxw1uwjizlMCXwzVwL1Qo/sTsDbo67lrIdH5mjX2HapCFbMz31BTX0IjJ+qqpBwDS2ydH4zpyOmHmIqn3kOh1DgCfZFtXSYzCKERKx5R5n5KtJShvjh7w7LBuD7VDB8u85Us7OpUUM7Ie+JbAPlxfGJ0IkBMuS6yAY2WOOTntDNEP65
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1004/1004 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/sftp/.ssh/authorized_keys2
debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/sftp/.ssh/authorized_keys2': No such file or directory
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: publickey authentication test: RSA-CERT key is not allowed
Failed publickey for sftp from 192.168.99.13 port 58972 ssh2: RSA-CERT SHA256:yYgNW3M5txAtXjj6jXnBVf6vI4NUnoNvfWPPtS4pewU ID debby (serial 0) CA RSA SHA256:W78bubCEvj75KxHJcasa9aclOddsDfKiOLd2uozMqKI
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com [preauth]
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 0.757ms, delaying 6.094ms (requested 6.850ms) [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
```

The issue seems to be this

```
mm_answer_keyallowed: publickey authentication test: RSA-CERT key is not allowed
```

Comment: Can you get more detailed logs with `LogLevel DEBUG3` in the sshd config?